# Can a black pudding corrode a leather tunic?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, armor

Our party had a run in with a black pudding this weekend and it permanently damaged a fellow party member's metal armor which was **covered** by a leather tunic.

The character in question always wears a leather tunic over their [mithral chain shirt](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/5381-mithral-armor) and [the wording on the black pudding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16808-black-pudding) says, "*The pudding can eat through 2-inch-thick, nonmagical wood or metal in 1 round.*"

I understand if it had a clear shot at the armor, of course. But it didn't and the page says, "nonmagical wood or metal" which seems pretty specific to me to not include other organic material.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Yes, but not the mithral armor underneath it.

Mithral (and adamantine) armors are listed under the "Magic Items" section of text in the DMG, and are listed directly in the magic items tables. They follow the rules for magical items, and are treated as magical items for any terms or conditions that discriminate based on such.

JC confirms in [this twitter post circa 2017 when it still meant something.](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/928368184075231232?lang=en)

However, if the default ruling at your table is that mithral and adamantine *don't* count as magical items, a leather tunic could be considered clothes with an AC value of 10. Another attack from the black ooze reads

> Pseudopod. Melee Weapon Attack: +5 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target.
> Hit: 6 (1d6 + 3) bludgeoning damage plus 18 (4d8) acid damage. In
> addition, nonmagical armor worn by the target is partly dissolved and
> takes a permanent and cumulative −1 penalty to the AC it offers. The
> armor is destroyed if the penalty reduces its AC to 10.

In this reading, the tunic would be destroyed on first contact unless it's magical. But this reading also implies that none of my assumptions about the rules in your game are necessarily accurate, so you might want to have a talk with your DM.

Comment: I didn't notice that part, as I got hung up on the section I quoted. Thanks for the information! It makes sense now.

Comment: You probably also want to address whether it can corrode the leather as that is the question posited in the title.

Comment: @Akixkisu The leather is the vest, unless I'm missing something. The answer does specifically address that, treating a vest as clothing (ac10 armor) which by the definition of the pseudopod attack is destroyed on hit if its AC is reduced to 10. ...Annnnd I should've used the word "tunic" clearly. :-D

Comment: @LloydLeinenweber There are two cases, a literal walk in (corrosive form) and an attack (Pseudopol) :)

Comment: @Akixkisu Ahh... except black pudding can't engulf in 5e (note the absence of the ability in its stat block). You're thinking of the gelatinous cube[1], which does have that ability in 5e. Black puddings also lack the ooze cube trait which lets you walk into and occupy their space.

[1]: https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16869-gelatinous-cube

Comment: @LloydLeinenweber Engulfing isn't necessary for touching. Well, sure you could argue, that you can't walk into anything that occupies a space, but that sounds odd.

Comment: @LloydLeinenweber A tunic isn't a vest; it's a long loose shirt that, in this context, goes over the armor with a belt around the waist. I suspect what the player has in mind is something like Link's armor from *Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess*, where he's wearing the classic green tunic, but a chain shirt underlayer peeks out around the edges. It's historically accurate; it was a common way to make armor more fashionable or advertise group affiliation. Just for a common example, if you think of a Templar, the famous white surcoat with red cross is a long sleeveless tunic.